# Android: custom List view with base adapter: How to set on click listner for row items?

Tags: java, android

I have successfully made a custom list view using base adapter.
However, I wish to create a on click listener for each row item. For example 
I press any row it does X Y Z blah blah.

Can someone help me find an example of how this is done? I was trying a google search earlier and I cant find an example of it being used with list view base adapter.

Thank you

Comment: setOnItemClickListener for lsitview search fro the same

Comment: what is confusing me is do I add the listener inside the public view GetView method?

Comment: depends on what you want. You want the roe click listener?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve it is finding the `View` in your `getView()` method of your custom `Adapter`.

The second parameter (usually called `convertView`, but doesn't have to) represents each one of the rows of your `ListView`. There's where you would declare your `onClickListener`, for example:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  ...
  convertView.setOnClickListener(...);
  ...
}
```